# TEXT datatype become MEMO in Ms.Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

Why did TEXT datatype in OleDbQuery become MEMO in Ms.Access?
Here is the screenshot

[image: OleDbQuery]
[image: Result in Ms.Access]

Please help...

Comment: Because MS Access Memo type corresponds to OLEDB Text one? What is the real problem?

Comment: [CREATE TABLE statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql) -- [Microsoft Access Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types)

Comment: Why? Because these types are synonyms. See [the](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/equivalent-ansi-sql-data-types) [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/microsoft/microsoft-access-data-types) on type mappings and synonyms in Access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use:

```
.. "] TEXT(n)"
```

where **n** is the size (max. length) of the field with a maximum for **n** of 255.